# Do i have to use fragments when using navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, navigation-drawer

I am currently building an app, and have decided to implement a navigation drawer for ease of use. currently, nearly all my classes extend activity, however, looking at the navigation drawer examples, they all use fragments.  do I have to use fragments for this, or can i keep my classes as activities?
I am only worried, as I have nearly finished the app, and have been told that they do not use the same methods.

Comment: Yes, changing activity to fragment is not a big thing :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the rich UI feature you would be better off using fragments.

If you have trouble calling methods you can always call

```
getActivity( ).TheMethod ( )
```

That will use the parent activity to call the relevant methods for you.

Comment: thank you very much, this is really helpful, does it affect performance in any way? or can i use it to my hearts content?

Answer (score 2):

No. you can acheive with Activity. Not required to use Fragment. 
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Read this reference , this has detail about Drawer layout.

Create a Base class called DrawerBaseActivity  which extends Activity.  Add all the drawer code to DrawerBaseActivity and Make all your custom activity extends DrawerBaseActivity.

The link reference  ask you to replace the fragment on drawerItemClick. But instead of fragment replace   create intent to an activity and start your activity.

```
     private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       switch (position)
      { case 1 :
          // start your respective activity
      }
    }
    }
```